# Change state using Mutation VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

So i have a Vuex Store setup which returns me `headers` and `desserts`. Inside my `desserts` i have a property setup named `display` which is initially false. I have a component `Row` which i am importing inside my parent component named `Table`. `Row` Components accepts a couple of props i.e. `Name` and `Display`. The `display` prop is what is returned from `desserts` from the vuex store.  I am trying to add a mutation such that on Click of the icon in my `Row` component, the `display.laptop` can be toggled to true and false. I have setup the `toggleLaptopDisplay` but i keep getting cannot read property laptop of undefined.

Please look at the complete [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-poincare-4r3s2?file=/src/store/index.js:433-452).

Here is the complete code:

The Vuex Store:-

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    headers: [{ text: "Dessert (100g serving)", value: "name" }],
    desserts: [
      { name: "Lollipop", display: { laptop: true } },
      { name: "Marshamallow", display: { laptop: false } }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    getHeaders: state => state.headers,
    getDesserts: state => state.desserts
  },
  mutations: {
    toggleLaptopDisplay(state) {
      state.desserts.display.laptop = !state.desserts.display.laptop;
    }
  }
});
```

This is the Table Component:-

```
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="getHeaders" :items="getDesserts" hide-actions select-all item-key="name">
    <template v-slot:headers="props">
      <tr>
        <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text">{{ header.text }}</th>
      </tr>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:items="props">
      <tr>
        <Row :name="props.item.name" :display="props.item.display"/>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import Row from "./Row";
export default {
  components: {
    Row
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      getHeaders: "getHeaders",
      getDesserts: "getDesserts"
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

This is the Row component:-

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{name}}
    <v-icon @click="toggleLaptopDisplay" :color="display.laptop ? 'info': '' ">smartphone</v-icon>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
export default {
  props: {
    name: String,
    display: Object
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      toggleLaptopDisplay: "toggleLaptopDisplay"
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Well `desserts` is an array, not an object. It has no property `display`. You would need to find the correct array item first using something like `find()` or `filter()` then and only then modify it's `display` properties/values. First update your code to update the mutation to take in some sort of name argument probably so that you can find the correct row/object to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to achieve what you want:

In your Row.vue add a method to select appropriate element:

```
<v-icon @click="toggleChange" :color="display.laptop ? 'info': '' ">smartphone</v-icon>
```

then in methods, create a method that will pass name of the element as payload:

```
methods: {
    toggleChange() {
        this.toggleLaptopDisplay(this.name)
      },
    ...mapMutations({
      toggleLaptopDisplay: "toggleLaptopDisplay"
    })
  }
```

finally, in store.js, use the payload and mutate selected element:

```
mutations: {
    toggleLaptopDisplay(state, payload) {
      state.desserts.find(dessert => dessert.name === payload).display.laptop = !state.desserts.find(dessert => dessert.name === payload).display.laptop
    }
  }
```

**[Edited Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-tereshkova-7xntu?file=/src/store/index.js)**

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, is there an alternative to using the `name` maybe and id because names can be duplicate and when i try to use `id` (which i passed) i get an error message.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is completely up to you how you want to design your application. I worked based on your example. In this case consider adding an id to your desserts, pass it as `prop` to `Row.vue`, and then use it instead (check edited example).

Comment: idk but i am running into issues when dealing with ids. Could you check this sanbox please: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-poincare-4r3s2?file=/src/components/Row.vue

Comment: It seems that you have not changed `@click` method.
Have a look at your `@click` in `Row.vue`. You are calling `toggleLaptopDisplay` directly instead of `toggleChange` because of that your mutation does not have payload. Please refer to the first point of my answer.